# collect function keyword arguments in dict in julia

Tags: julia, keyword-argument

How can I get the keyword arguments and their default values of a function in a dict in Julia?

E.g:

```
function foo(x; a = 1, b = 2, c= 3)
  # How do I get a dict of keyword arguments: Dict(a=>1, b=>2,c=3) ??,
  # so I can pass this Dict easily to another generic function taking v 
  # variable keyword arguments for further processing
end
```

Comment: `args = Dict(:a => a, :b => b, :c => c)` ?

Comment: cf https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-collect-keyword-arguments-in-a-dict/6693

Answer (score 4):

You can use the splat `...` operator:

```
function foo(x; kwargs...)
   Dict(kwargs)
end
```

or if you just want to pass it:

```
function foo(x; kwargs...)
   innerfunction(x; kwargs...)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a Dict like so:

```
function foo(x; a = 1, b = 2, c= 3)
  Dict(:a => a, :b => b, :c => c)
end
```